# Confused with the notation/halfway done and need a little help

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

Given 1 and 2

1) $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=6$

2) $w^{3}+z^{3}=5xy+12$

I must solve for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}$ at a constant $z$ at the point (x,y,z,w) = (1,-2,1,1) and the answer is -6/5, but I can't seem to get it.

Taking the partial derivative with respect to x yields the following result:

$3w^{2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} + 3z^{2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = 5x\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + y$

After rearranging the second equation, I obtained the following:

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} =\frac{( 5x\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+y - +3z^{2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})}{3w^{2}}  $

and taking the partial of the second I get:

$ 2x \frac{\partial x}{\partial w} + 2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial w} + 2z \frac{\partial z}{\partial w} $

Comment: You can put $ signs around the Latex so that it compiles.

Comment: Thanks @Seth. That was my first time using LaTex. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that partial derivatives in a $d$-dimensional environment are only defined when $d$ independent variables have been selected.

Two equations in four variables define a two-dimensional surface $S\subset{\mathbb R}^4$. In the problem at hand the variables $z$ and $w$ are selected as independent variables, and the two equations define $x$ and $y$ implicitly as functions of these, in the following way:
$$x^2(z,w)+y^2(z,w)=6-z^2, \quad 5x(z,w)y(z,w)=z^3+w^3-12\ .$$
Taking ${\partial\over\partial w}$ in both equations we obtain
$$2x(z,w)x_w+2y(z,w)y_w=0,\qquad 5y(z,w)x_w+5x(z,w)y_w=3w^2\ .$$
We now plug in the point $(1,-2,1,1)\in S$ and obtain
$$2 x_w-4y_w=0,\qquad -10 x_w+5y_w=3\ ,$$
from which we easily deduce
$${\partial x\over\partial w}(1,1)=-{2\over5}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you, @ChristianBlatter. Your procedure makes sense, but the answer is -6/5. So then, the answer in the book is incorrect?

Comment: Check whether you have copied the equations in your book and the requested partial derivative correctly.

Comment: you are right .I just confirmed with a friend. it is-2/5

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial }{\partial w}$ means deriving **with respect to w**, that is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}$ is the derivative of $x$ as a function of $w$  with respect to $w$ ($x$ is a multivariate function).

Deriving both sides of $(2)$ with respect to $w$ we get:

$$\frac{\partial (w^3 +z^3) }{\partial w}=\frac{\partial (5xy +12)}{\partial w}$$

By the chain and product rules:

$$3w^2 +3x^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial w}=5\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}y + 5x\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}$$

Hence, solving for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}$:

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}=\frac{3w^2 +3x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}-5x\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}}{5y}$$

Comment: Thank you. I solved for it, but not correctly. That makes a lot of sense. Do we need to do anything with the second equation at all?

Comment: I derived the second equation. You could apply the same process to the first getting $2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}+2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}$ which can also be solved to obtain a different expression for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}$, but I do not know if that is useful for your problem.

Comment: It was just a matter of using both and subbing one in for the other once you realize z is constant.